# Installing Perl Module in specified directory

Tags: perl, installation, perl-module

I am trying to install one of the Perl module in my server (ubuntu droplet from Digital Ocean). I wanted this module to be installed in `/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/` directory which I have already created.

This is specific to one module. I don't want to install it in default path like `/usr/bin/perl`. I wanted it to be installed in above mentioned path.

Here are the list of commands which I executed to install the `Email::Reply` perl module.

```
Downloaded module from metacpan
tar xvfz Email-Reply-1.204.tar.gz
cd Email-Reply-1.204/
perl Makefile.PL PREFIX=/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/
su
<password_for_root>
make
make test 
make install
```

When I execute `make install` command the following output got displayed on terminal screen

```
Manifying 1 pod document
Installing /home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/share/perl/5.26.1/Email/Reply.pm
Installing /home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/man/man3/Email::Reply.3pm
Appending installation info to /home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1/perllocal.pod
```

And I could see the module got installed in `/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/share/perl/5.26.1/Email/Reply.pm` path, which is not right path which I mentioned in `PREFIX=`.

Strange thing here I wrote one small script which uses `Email::Reply` module by mentioning module path in shebang line

Code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -I/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/share/perl/5.26.1/

use EMail::Reply;

print "Hi\n";
```

still its throws an error

```
Can't locate EMail/Reply.pm in @INC (you may need to install the EMail::Reply module) (@INC contains: /home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/share/perl/5.26.1/ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.26.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.26 /usr/share/perl/5.26 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at test.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 3.
```

I want this module to be installed in `/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/`
How to achieve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

This is what [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) can be used for, and [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm) supports it by default:

```
$ cpanm -l /home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts Email::Reply
```

This will install it to `/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/perl5`.

Alternatively you can recreate the options local::lib sets for this case, the important one for this case is [PERL_MM_OPT](https://perldoc.pl/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#ENVIRONMENT).

```
$ env PERL_MM_OPT='INSTALL_BASE=/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts' cpanm Email::Reply
```

Importantly, note that all of this is case sensitive, you must `use Email::Reply;`.

Comment: Thanks @Grinnz. This is much helpful answer. But it failed to install module completely. At the end I got this message - ```! Installing the dependencies failed: Module 'Email::MIME' is not installed
! Bailing out the installation for Email-Reply-1.204.
10 distributions installed
``` Whether dependencies installed automatically or we should do it manually?

Comment: @vinodk89, that's a different problem, please [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with the details of the Email::MIME installation that went wrong.

Comment: @daxim Thank you. Here while installing one more thing I noticed is whenever I execute the above command which @Grinnz has given, the module is being installed in ```/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts/lib/perl5``` by default even after I give the path as ```/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts``` in command. Why so?

Comment: @vinodk89, that's working as intended. If you need a detailed explanation, [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @vinodk89 If you are installing something that needs dependencies, I recommend using the cpanm command which will handle everything, and not attempting to manually set all of the local::lib variables, because you will need more than just PERL_MM_OPT.

Comment: @vinodk89 You can see all of the variables that would be set by local::lib by running `perl -Mlocal::lib=/home/vinod/my_test_folder/perl_practice/scripts`. This will not set anything but can be eval'd to set it in your environment, as described in the local::lib docs. It will install modules to `lib/perl5` and executables to `bin` and manpages to `man`.